# Where in the world are these fonts being loaded on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am attempting to transfer my domain from http to https. I have installed a wordpress theme, but I modified it slightly. Now, I can't figure out where the font.google.com is being loaded from. I have searched literally for hours. Nothing found in functions.php and other similar files.

I remember vaguely that there were lots of files be called, so I decided to add it to this list. Now I don't know where that might be to change it to https. Any idea where the scripts are located that break my https in my wordpress install?

The domain is [floridamaids.com](http://floridamaids.com) Thanks for any help deciphering this riddle.

Comment: Download a copy of the website and use a text editor like notepad++ to search through the files looking for mentions of "font.google.com"

Comment: It's being called in some kind of theme functions file. You need to search your entire theme for `googleFontsRoboto-css` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are loaded from 
[shortcodes.css](https://floridamaids.com/wp-content/themes/advertica/advertica/SketchBoard/functions/shortcodes/css/shortcodes.css)

Comment: Well, sure...but that's not the only place they're loaded. Roboto and Lato are both being loaded in `wp_head()`, which suggests they're being enqueued by the theme...or possibly a plugin.

Comment: I made my answer community wiki, so you can feel free to add any other places you found the fonts. I'm not into getting free reputation from this answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure how I overlooked this. I thought for sure it was being loaded in. If you don't mind, how did you find the source so easily. I'm using chrome and it just said line 64 on inspect element...

Comment: In chrome, I checked css files you page loads. And then looked in each one of them for the word "google". With access to source code it would be simple search for word Google in *.css files